# Installation counter

Tags: android, counter

Whether there is a possibility and if someone can show by example how to do code that will have an installation counter in it? What is the specific issue, it is necessary that .apk can only be installed on 10 devices, and when an attempt is made on installation on the 11th device to show a notification that the limit is met.

Comment: build service that sign the device when the application loaded, in case the next device will pass you limit you can prevent the application from working remotely...

Comment: Is there any example where I could look?

Comment: it's more complex, there is many ways to do this

Comment: i'm sure there is already a solution somewhere and i ask people that if they have some link or can post their code to do so. thanks in advance.